# Why are the file permissions after apt install different from dpkg -c

Tags: apt, permissions, dpkg

I am just curious about what decides the file permissions for files installed by `apt`.

Running `apt download transmission` and then `dpkg -c transmission-daemon_2.94-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb` shows that all files belong to `root`:

```
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./etc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./etc/default/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       562 2019-01-02 12:50 ./etc/default/transmission-daemon
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./etc/init/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       654 2019-01-02 12:50 ./etc/init/transmission-daemon.conf
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./etc/init.d/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      1975 2019-01-02 12:50 ./etc/init.d/transmission-daemon
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./etc/transmission-daemon/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       303 2019-01-02 12:50 ./etc/transmission-daemon/README.json
-rw-r--r-- root/root       523 2019-01-02 12:50 ./etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./lib/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./lib/systemd/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./lib/systemd/system/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       284 2020-03-26 01:56 ./lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./usr/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root    543528 2020-03-26 01:56 ./usr/bin/transmission-daemon
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./usr/share/bug/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./usr/share/bug/transmission-daemon/
-rw-r--r-- root/root        95 2019-01-02 12:50 ./usr/share/bug/transmission-daemon/presubj
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./usr/share/man/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./usr/share/man/man1/
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1992 2020-03-26 01:56 ./usr/share/man/man1/transmission-daemon.1.gz
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./var/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./var/lib/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./var/lib/transmission-daemon/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./var/lib/transmission-daemon/downloads/
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./usr/share/doc/transmission-daemon -> transmission-common
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json -> /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2020-03-26 01:56 ./var/lib/transmission-daemon/info -> .config/transmission-daemon
```

But then running `ls -lha /etc/transmission-daemon` after `apt install transmission-daemon` shows me that some files does not belong to root:

```
total 16K
drwxrwsr-x   2 root                debian-transmission 4.0K Jun 20 19:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 106 root                root                4.0K Jun 20 19:10 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root                root                 303 Jan  2  2019 README.json
-rw-rw----   1 debian-transmission debian-transmission  523 Jan  2  2019 settings.json
```

Comment: There Are Mainly Two Determining Factors.  
1. The Actual Program/Package may have commands/scripts to set/change ownership & permissions as so required.  
2. Umask is often used to set the default permissions for new files upon them being created in a given directory. [More on umask here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/umask-command-in-linux-with-examples/)

Comment: Where are these umasks defined? And I've looked into the deb package, it doesn't seem to have any post-install scripts included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to view the posi-install script used by transmission-daemon, run:
`apt download transmission-daemon`

**transmission-daemon_3.00-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb** will be downloaded.
(Your version number may differ a bit)

- Now extract the .deb package using your favourite archive extractor or by right-clicking the deb file then *extract here* using your file manager.
- In the extracted directory, You should see: "control.tar.zst", "data.tar.zst", "debian-binary"
- Now extract **control.tar.zst**
- You should see the scripts. (We are interested in `preinst` & `postinst`)
- Feel Free to Have a Look at the `preinst` script. (has just a few lines)
- Once done, Open the `postinst` script and have a look at the `chperms()` function and its usage shortly after.

Happy Exploring!